# QML opens GUI window and console

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, console, declarative

I'm trying to get a working QML app. It's all fine except the fact that when I run my app it opens the QML window but also a console window. Why? This is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QDeclarativeView view;

    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myfile.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}

Rectangle {
    width: 940
    height: 670
    color: red
}
```

Comment: what platform, what build environment

Comment: sorry, Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7, I'm running the app from the debug environment

Comment: check properties->linker->system, subsystem:console will also create an output console, susbsystem:windows doesn't

Comment: you are a genious! Put your solution in an answer and I will accept it! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

For CMake users.

The problems occurred to me for MSVC and MinGW builds for Windows. (Even when *not* starting from an IDE.)

The solution were the following lines in CMakeLists:

```
if (WIN32)
    set(WIN32_ON_OFF_SWITCH "WIN32")
else ()
    set(WIN32_ON_OFF_SWITCH "")
endif ()

add_executable(SomeExe
    ${WIN32_ON_OFF_SWITCH}
    #...
)
```

This exactly sets the target system away from console, like mentioned in a comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The console is for debugging with QDebug();

You can disable it by deleting line:

```
CONFIG += console
```

in your .pro file.

Answer (score 1):

For qbs set the property
`consoleApplication: false`
for your application.
For example:

```
    Application {
    // consoleApplication: false // permanently disable the console for the application
    Properties {
        condition: qbs.buildVariant == "debug"
        consoleApplication: true //show console
    }

    Properties {
        condition: qbs.buildVariant == "release"
        consoleApplication: false //hide console
    }
}
```