# What is equivalent of qmake (.pro file) CONFIG -= console in CMAKE

Tags: cmake, qml, qmake, qt6

I have build QML application and run it. But besides of GUI running console. I know how switch off console in qmake (.pro file) CONFIG -= console. But I do not understand how it works in CMake? I tried [QML opens GUI window and console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856513/qml-opens-gui-window-and-console) but it does not helped me.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(APSMDClient LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# QtCreator supports the following variables for Android, which are identical to qmake Android variables.
# Check https://doc.qt.io/qt/deployment-android.html for more information.
# They need to be set before the find_package(...) calls below.

#if(ANDROID)
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
#    if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
#        set(ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libcrypto.so
#            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/libssl.so)
#    endif()
#endif()

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Quick Qml LinguistTools QuickControls2 REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Quick LinguistTools QuickControls2 REQUIRED)


set(TS_FILES APSMDClient_ru_RU.ts)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        qml.qrc
        ${TS_FILES}
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(APSMDClient
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )

    qt_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(APSMDClient SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        add_executable(APSMDClient
          ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()

    qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${TS_FILES})
endif()

# Added
add_executable(APSMDClient WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(APSMDClient PRIVATE Qt6::QuickControls2 Qt6::Qml)

target_compile_definitions(APSMDClient
  PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
target_link_libraries(APSMDClient
  PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Quick)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the console window you can use either

```
add_executable(APSMDClient WIN32 ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
```

or

```
add_executable(APSMDClient ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
if (WIN32)
    set_target_properties(APSMDClient PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
endif()
```

`qt_add_executable` is a Qt wrapper for `add_executable`.

Comment: Isn't it identical to what is indicated in the link provided by the OP?

Comment: @eyllanesc Partially. It adds the syntax for directly setting the property on the target.

Comment: It is the same written in another way

Comment: Unfortunately it does not helped me. In console Problems: crt0_c.c:-1: ошибка: undefined reference to `WinMain'

Comment: That's a linker error. You need to link to the appropriate Qt libraries. Try adding the relevant parts of your CMakeLists.txt to your question and specify what Qt version are you using.

Comment: @vre C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин I adapted the answer to your CMakeLists.txt settings.

Comment: @vre I changed to APSMDClient but it does not helped.

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:60 (add_executable):
  add_executable cannot create target "APSMDClient" because another target
  with the same name already exists.  The existing target is an executable
  created in source directory "D:/Projects/apsmd_client/APSMDClient".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details

Comment: qt version 6.0.3

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин You do not need to repeat add_executable here, This is not supported by CMake.  Either add WIN32 to your present calls or add the set_target_properties command after the target has been created.

Comment: @vre I insert "WIN32" into  if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(APSMDClient WIN32
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    ) It helps me